# No bootable devices, when loading. GPT detected, please create BIOS-Boot partition appears when I want to boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

**I am completely stuck and not a good linux user, please help me. I have Boot Repair "Info Summary":**

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230725_0618]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at 
    sector 751194112 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not 
    be found at this location.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p8: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p9: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on nvme0n1p7
OS#2:   Windows 7 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] GP107M [GeForce MX350] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: XMACM5B1P0201(1.2) from TIMI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled.
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(1,GPT,b246e31b-794f-4cb2-99ea-4931ba578b9e,0x800,0x1e3b7df)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p9   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p9   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p9   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 8265B33F-51F3-4294-90F8-1F64DCF3A439
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p2    534528     796671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    796672  306222368 305425697 145.6G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 306223104  307996671   1773568   866M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 307996672  698621671 390625000 186.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p6 998118031 1000215182   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 698621952  786511871  87889920  41.9G Linux root (x86-64)
nvme0n1p8 786511872  806043647  19531776   9.3G Linux swap
nvme0n1p9 806658048  998117375 191459328  91.3G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 15.12 GiB, 16231956480 bytes, 31703040 sectors
Disk identifier: 59C0A7C4-1ED6-4BDD-82D9-2F5CA3275F50
      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 31703006 31700959 15.1G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:16.2GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:JetFlash Transcend 16GB:;
1:1049kB:16.2GB:16.2GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-00000:;
2:274MB:408MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:408MB:157GB:156GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:157GB:158GB:908MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:158GB:358GB:200GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
7:358GB:403GB:45.0GB:ext4::;
8:403GB:413GB:10.0GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
9:413GB:511GB:98.0GB:ext4::;
6:511GB:512GB:1074MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme0n1: 0.02MiB:261MiB:261MiB
nvme0n1: 393576MiB:393876MiB:300MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     B88C-F987                            b246e31b-794f-4cb2-99ea-4931ba578b9e UBUNTU 22_0 Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p2                                               7eda6536-c1e6-40b7-806f-c2d0cbda6e19             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     F2103B84103B4F3B                     f18b68fe-ca21-4705-bf28-744fa2b31e27 Windows 10  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     30A806F9A806BD7A                     ddd23fd6-082b-4549-8f3e-78c49586162b             
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     96C6D8DCC6D8BDA5                     d450ffbc-3fc7-428f-9aed-c8394cbf0ef2 Data        Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     A6543BDA543BAC45                     83836265-0c2f-430e-a3d3-57b7346d839b Windows_RE  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p7 ext4     28a46378-80c8-427b-99b3-4a62e9ea31d7 b7fa0ee9-35c6-48d8-b748-600bf6c868dc             
├─nvme0n1p8 swap     8c49649c-496a-4ac0-9e63-a628f5a1facb 5b8bbb9c-5e7b-48fc-a08f-c00ea440763e             
└─nvme0n1p9 ext4     d0882226-2ee5-49f1-b2e5-162408f63ca6 17905777-3fe8-4b19-bf74-f9aa64b0c179             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3          53.2G  63% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4         169.3M  80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5            19G  90% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6           577M  44% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7          11.2G  67% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7
/dev/nvme0n1p9          56.4G  32% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p9
/dev/sda1               11.5G  24% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p7/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   28a46378-80c8-427b-99b3-4a62e9ea31d7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic   28a46378-80c8-427b-99b3-4a62e9ea31d7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic   28a46378-80c8-427b-99b3-4a62e9ea31d7
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-9C3B-09DD
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p7/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=28a46378-80c8-427b-99b3-4a62e9ea31d7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=9C3B-09DD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p9 during installation
UUID=d0882226-2ee5-49f1-b2e5-162408f63ca6 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p8 during installation
UUID=8c49649c-496a-4ac0-9e63-a628f5a1facb none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p7/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p7: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 371.379161835 = 398.765338624  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 368.897468567 = 396.100640768  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 369.488277435 = 396.735016960  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic                 2
 368.897468567 = 396.100640768  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic                 1
 369.488277435 = 396.735016960  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 350.878902435 = 376.753352704  boot/initrd.img                                2
 368.237194061 = 395.391676416  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic              1
 350.878902435 = 376.753352704  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic              2
 368.237194061 = 395.391676416  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p7: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown MBR on /dev/sda

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
e3bc684fcde8b14d96e7fbcaf984b709



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to remove grub-efi) and reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p7 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

Windows-on-GPT detected. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?Windows-on-GPT detected. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
```

Comment: Do not confuse UEFI & BIOS boot. With gpt Windows has to be UEFI boot & then Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI boot mode. You do not need bios_grub partition as that is only for BIOS boot mode. Be sure to boot Boot-Repair or live installer only in UEFI mode & have system set to boot in UEFI mode. But issue really seems to be that you are missing p1 and have space in front of p2. Did you delete the ESP - efi system partition which is required for UEFI boot. You need to recreate that partition and reinstall Windows & Ubuntu boot loaders. Use Boot-Repair in UEFI mode to reinstall UEFI grub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.